# Why aren't smartphone batteries parallel?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, parallel

So I'm thinking, imagine a phone with a 3000mah battery. Then if we divide that battery in two, we get the same capacity but those batteries can now be charged twice as fast. What's the mistake with this thinking?

Comment: The way to improve charge rate is to change how the battery is constructed in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends where you think the limitation of the charging rate is coming from.

If you think that 'a battery' can be charged at 'X amps', regardless of the capacity of the battery, then yes, two small batteries could be charged twice as fast as one larger battery.

But it doesn't work like that. Charge rate limitation tends to be in terms of C, the battery capacity. If you split a battery with capacity C into two, then you end up with two C/2 capacity batteries. Each of these smaller batteries takes the same time to charge, because you can only run half the amount of current into each.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the energies *density* (in means of mAh per cm^3), which is somewhat constant for a specific battery technology (like Lithium-Ion/Polymer). No matter, how you divide cells - with no additional room, you won't get more capacity. In fact, the opposite is the case, as you have to invest space for more casing and other "offset" efforts.

### Edit:

Charging also won't speed up much, as the capacity for each cell would be roughly half of the initial capacity. Charging speed is traditionally somewhat proportional to the capacity. Say you charge the battery with "1C" which means one times the capacity taken as a current.
Therefore my initial answer will also help: as the resulting capacity will rather be less than the initial, the charging will also be slower.

I'm aware, that there exist more sophisticated charging algorithms, but explaining them in this context would lead a bit far.

Comment: I don't think the question was about increasing capacity. Guess you should read it again...

Comment: @macmade I guess you're right.

Answer (score -1):

you might open  your smart phone  and  see  how  it  is  constructed.
1) if  it  is  constructed  such  that   they  make  3.7volts  by  making  a  series  connection ( example = two AA  batteries  connected  to  make  a  long  line)... then   you  might  connect  a  wire  or  charger   to  EACH   set.
figure this... to  create  a  3.7  volts  could  be  3 AA  batteries  in  series  that  is  1.25+1.25+1.25  is  almost  3.7 volts... in  such  case   to  speed  up  charging... you  might  charge  each   battery separately   by  your  modifications...

2) if  your  3.7 volts  battery   is   made  chemically  as  one  set,  like  a  one  piece  AA... you  cannot  charge  it   simply as  a  two  set  or  3 set  battery...though  you  can  modify and  insert  anywhere (theoretically)  a  charger.

3) I noticed  that  samsung  s5  battery  charger  has  an  output  of  5.3 volts  while  common  chargers  are  5 volts.  the extra 0.3 volts  makes  charging  a  bit  faster, though this  way  must  be  compensated  or  made  possible  by  your  device  and  battery  itself.

Comment: Can you name a smartphone that uses AA batteries?